# A question about submersion

Tags: differential-geometry

I know that a smooth surjective map need not be a submersion. But can we say that every smooth quotient map is a submersion? If it is not true, can you give a counter example about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a counterexample, consider the map $$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto x^{3}.$$
This map is:

- smooth,
- surjective,
- open, being the composition of the open map $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and the homeomorphism $x\mapsto x^{3}$.

So it is indeed a smooth quotient map. But it is not a submersion, since the derivative $df=(3x^{2}\ 0)$ is zero at all points $(0,y)$ on the $y$-axis.

Comment: Thank you studiosus.I understand the example.